# Ruby/Rails security alerts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, rubygems

How do Ruby developers keep updated on ruby and rubygem security alerts and updates?. I found out about this today:

https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/22915701-january-14-2013-security-vulnerabilities-httparty-extlib-crack-nori-update-these-gems-immediately

and wonder how developers usually keep up with these types of alerts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

For Rails, just register for email updates in the Rails security google group :

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-security

Answer (score 4):

The [Ruby Security Announcements](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ruby-security-ann) list is specifically for security issues in Ruby and Rubygems.

Answer (score 4):

I actually [wrote about this a few weeks back](http://gavinmiller.io/2015/staying-up-to-date-with-security-alerts/). These are the things that I would recommend:

1. Follow the [Ruby](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ruby-security-ann) and [Rails](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-security) security mailing lists.
2. Use [CVE Reports](https://www.cvedetails.com/) to get details of security alerts as soon as you can. CVE stands for "Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures" and it's an industry standard reporting mechanism.
3. Keep your dependencies as up to date as you can. Run `bundle outdated` to get this information. Keeping your test suite at > 85% is going to make dependency upgrading much easier.
4. Create a process for your team so you can stay up to date on squashing security issues. I elaborate in the blog post on how to do that.
5. Use tooling like `bundle-audit`, `AppCanary`, `Hakiri`, or `Gemnasium` to auto-detect gem security issues. These are easy tools to insert into a CI environment.

Answer (score 3):

Also check out the [bundler-audit gem](https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit) to automate this process. It will check your gems for known vulnerabilities and also recommend some improvements regarding the update process in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think these two sources should get you that info as soon as it's available. You could also sign up for an account at rubygems.org and add Rails to your RSS feed.

- [Ruby on Rails on Twitter](https://twitter.com/rails)
- [Rails core mailing list](http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-core)

Answer (score 0):

Also the [Ruby 5 Podcast](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/) is a twice weekly resource and only takes 10 minutes of your time per week.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you find it hard to keep find the time to look for updates or perform the actual update: Use mini habits to e.g. update software every Monday, as I described in [the week with a Rails security strategy](http://bauland42.com/articles/a-week-with-a-rails-security-strategy/)